# I would like to create some simple printable documents in Java with rows/columns and large fonts, but I'm not sure how

Tags: java

I have written a java program to create math questions for my son, and I would like to print the questions off as a worksheet, in a nice big font. So a few (like 5) rows and a few (like 3) columns of questions per page, nice and easy to read and work with.  The computer I program on doesn't have access to a printer, so I would like to save them to a file and then later print them off.

I don't believe a standard text file will allow changing the font size.

I'd like to use a free, open source library.

I'm not sure what will be the easiest way to go: pdf, OpenDocument, HTML, something else?

First I started looking at generating pdf files, but without much early success I decided to try OpenDocument format. I installed the apache odfdo-java-0.8.11-incubating.jar and the xercesimpl.jar, but I am now getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/rootdev/javardfa/StatementSink errors. I can't seem to figure that out and have spent a few hours trying to sort it out.

So I am taking a step back and wondering if there is a better way.

Any help will be appreciated. I am using IntelliJ Community Edition on Ubuntu with java 1.8.

Answer (score 0):

Visit http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library. The license is LGPL. This is a library for Java. You can to generate rtf, pdf, csv documents.

Answer (score 0):

For design the report you can use iReport. Visit https://sourceforge.net/projects/ireport/files/iReport/iReport-5.6.0/. This is a powerful tool that you must to use with JasperReport.

Good luck